# Defined color is not showing on drawable element - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, kotlin-android

I got a problem with color on my button.xml file in drawable folder.
I have 2 rounded buttons, one with green background and one with grey. This is the code for my grey rounded button:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/mesi_grey" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Color is defined in colors.xml, and it's showing in drawable item:

[image]

In layout, I created a button and called `android:background="@drawable/round_button_grey""`

Code for both buttons:

```xml
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_grey"
            android:text="Prekliči" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_bike_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_green"
            android:text="Potrdi" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

As the result I get both buttons green, but I would like to have left button in my grey color.

[image: the result]

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: go to `Buid`>`Clean Project` wait until clean and then click `Build`>`Rebuild Project` works.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to gray your `Button` Background. Use this attribute `android:backgroundTint="@color/mesi_grey"`. And if you want to make your custom Button with a `Gradient` background then you have to use `ImageButton`.
Your new XML is below

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/mesi_grey"
            android:text="Prekliči" />
```

let me know if you want a custom Backgroud with a gradient button. I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks! I need just basic color background, no need for gradient

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that my green color defined in themes.xml override everything else?

```xml
<!-- Mesi Theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Mesibike" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color.-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mesi_green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/mesi_green</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!--<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item> -->
    </style>
```